# Как добавить еще такой же блок расчета стоимости?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Соорудил простой расчет стоимости.
Подскажите, каким образом при нажатии на кнопку `[+]`, дополнительно вывести такие же блоки `<div class="blok">`, как в моем исходнике? (И чтобы сумма итоговая подсчитывала все).

```html
<style>
#cvet, #count {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 margin: 3px 0 10px;
}

#rrr, .add{
    padding: 10px 15px 10px;
    border: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#fff;
 background:#343c63;
}

#stoimost {
    font-weight:bold;
}

.forma {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 padding: 10px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<h3>Расчет стоимости</h3>
<div class="forma">
<div id="name" rebest='yes'><br>
Что сдаем в химчистку:<br> <select id="cvet">
<option value="empy">---</option>
<option value="poduska">Подушка</option>
<option value="matras">Матрас</option>
<option value="postelnoe">Постельное белье</option>
</select>
<p>Количество:<br> <input type="number" min="1" max="100" class="val2" value="1" id="count"></p>
<br>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<a href="#" class="add">+</a>
<button id="rrr">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
<p><div id="stoimost"></div></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".add").click(function(){
var links = $("[rebest='yes']").length;
$("#name").clone().attr('id', 'name' + links).appendTo(".forma");
});
});

function raschitat() {
cvet  = document.getElementById('cvet').value;
switch (cvet) {
   case "empy":
      cena = 0;
      break
   case "poduska":
      cena = 440;
      break
   case "matras":
      cena = 1200;
      break   
    case "postelnoe":
      cena = 880;
      break   
   
}
var count = +document.getElementById('count').value;
stoimost = cena * count;
document.getElementById('stoimost').innerHTML = "Стоимость: "+ stoimost +" грн.";

}
rrr.onclick = raschitat;
</script>
```

[Мой исходник](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwvRXj)

Answer (score 1):

Если подгружаете JQuery, то пользуйтесь этим. Переделал и добавил логику в скрипте.  Хороший тон - "`id` для JS, `class` для CSS". Расставил всё по местам.

Адаптивно и функционально теперь (а если `$('#run').click(fCalculate);` заменить на `$('.container').change(fCalculate);`, то надобность в кнопке запуска отпадёт, и итоговая сумма будет автоматически пересчитываться, при любом изменении параметров).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Функция удаления блока, при выборе пустого значения */
  $('div.order_item').find('select.control').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('selectedIndex') == 0 && $('div.order_item').length > 1) {
      $(this).parents('div.order_item').remove();
    }
  });
  var oOrderItem = $('div.order_item').clone(true);
  /* Обработчик добавления блока */
  $('#add').click(function() {
    oOrderItem.clone(true).appendTo('div.order');
  });
});

var aPrices = [0, 440, 1200, 880]; // Массив цен

/* Функция подсчёта */
function fCalculate() {
  let nTotal = 0;
  $('div.order_item').each(function(index, element) {
    nTotal +=
      aPrices[$(element).find('select.control').prop('selectedIndex')] *
      $(element).find('input.control').val();
  });
  $('.total').html('Стоимость: ' + nTotal + ' грн.');
}
/* Обработчик кнопки подсчёта */
$('#run').click(fCalculate);
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 420px;
  min-width: 240px;
}

.order {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.order_item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px 0 5px;
}

.order_item:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.order_item p {
  margin: 0;
}

.control {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 29px;
  margin: 5px 0 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

input.control {
  padding-left: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  background: #343c63;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.total {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Расчёт стоимости</h3>
  <div class="order">
    <div class="order_item" rebest="yes">
      <div>
        <p>Что сдаём в химчистку:</p>
        <select class="control">
          <option selected> --- </option>
          <option>Подушка (440 &#8372;)</option>
          <option>Матрас (1200 &#8372;)</option>
          <option>Постельное бельё (880 &#8372;)</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Количество:</p>
        <input type="number" min="1" class="control" value="1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="btn" id="add">+</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn" id="run">Рассчитать стоимость</a>
  <p class="total"></p>
</div>
```